# Vector chain rule problem

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

I have the following equation that I'm struggling to understand within a proof for Kelvin's Circulation Theorem within Rotating Shallow Water:

$\frac{d}{dt}\oint_{c(u)}\textbf{v}\cdot d\textbf{x} = \oint_{c(u)}(\partial_t\textbf{v} + \textbf{u}\cdot\nabla\textbf{v} + v_j\nabla u^j)\cdot d\textbf{x}$

where $\textbf{v} = \textbf{v}(t,x(t)$) and $\frac{d}{dt}$ is the material derivative (I know it's normally capitalised by my professor for some reason hasn't).

I understand the chain rule is coming into play here, but shouldn't the last term correspond to $\textbf{v}_\textbf{x}\textbf{x}_t$, ie

$\nabla v_j \cdot u^j$ ?

I'm just really unsure where the last term has appeared.

Comment: How are $u$ and $c(u)$ defined?

Comment: $u$ is a horizontal velocity and $c(u)$ is a closed loop moving with $u$ (which is why I assume the material derivative is being used here)

Comment: Does this help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I think that confused me more! I've never seen the Leibniz integral rule before